# How to increase font of a Multi page caption

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with 12 multi pages. I want to increase the font size of each page caption,as the default font is small. searched lot of blogs for this, but not getting any solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that only for the whole multipage not for a single page. Use this example:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  MultiPage1.Font.Size = 16
  MultiPage1.Font.Name = "Courier"
  MultiPage1.Font.Bold = True
  MultiPage1.Font.Italic = True
End Sub
```

**Edit:** You can also do it fix in the settings of the multipage. NOT in the settins for the pages:
[image]

Comment: thanks for the response. I tested with Multipage properties as shown in your picture, its worked for me.